# CNN model for 3d model generation

Tags: conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am experimenting with Convolutional Neural Networks. I am training a CNN model using a single mesh of 12500 vertices and 4 anthropometric measurements (height,waist,chest,hip), i want to see how the model can learn to generate the same 12500 vertices when the same anthropometric input is entered for testing. I do not intend to feed any different data to the model. The same measurements will be used but my model is generating 12500 different vertices. My code is below

Note: I tried increasing the epoch from 100 to 1000 and then i tried tweaking the learning rate but to no avail.

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv1D, Reshape

```
# Set the random seeds for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create a Sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Add a Convolutional layer with 64 filters of size 2 and 'relu' activation function
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,1)))

# Add another Convolutional layer with 128 filters of size 1 and 'relu' activation function
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))

# Flatten the tensor output from the previous layer
model.add(Flatten())

# Add a Dense layer with 512 units and 'relu' activation function
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

# Add a Dense layer with a number of units that matches the total number of elements
model.add(Dense(37500))

# Reshape the output into the desired shape
model.add(Reshape((-1, 12500, 3)))

# Compile the model with 'adam' optimizer and 'mean_squared_error' loss function
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model for more epochs
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100)
```